# Finding Inverse Exponential of Number Using C or Objective C

Tags: c, objective-c, iphone

How would a programmer like myself learn how to find an inverse exponential of a number? on my calculator 2nd LN or e^x. It is similar in concept to the neperien function on calculator  e.g.  the log of 2 is about 0.3
and the inverse log or 10^x  of 0.3 is 2.)

Note: This is to be used within an iPhone project using iPhone SDK

Note: Here is an example of what I am needing to compute: then 0.91831 is raised to the power of the inverse exponential of .773848284, or, 0.91831^2.168332164 = 0.831282.

Comment: is this the same thing as using the pow function ??

Comment: Which do you want, the log(x) or e**x? There is no such thing as "inverse exponential".

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear what you mean by "inverse exponential", but I'm going to list all of the potentially relevant math library functions and hopefully you can figure out which one you actually need.

- `exp(x)` returns `e^x` (where `e` is the base of the natural logarithm, 2.71828...).
- `exp2(x)` returns `2^x`.
- `log(x)` returns the natural logarithm of `x` (the number `a` that satisfies `e^a = x`).
- `log2(x)` returns the base-2 logarithm of `x`.
- `log10(x)` returns the base-10 logarithm of `x`.
- `pow(x,y)` returns x^y.

All of these functions are available on the iPhone.  In order to get the prototypes, you will need to include the header that defines them.  Add the line `#include <math.h>` to the beginning of your source file to do so.

If you need a more precise explanation of exactly what any of these functions do, or examples of their use, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [`exp` function](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/exp.php) in `<math.h>`.  Or if you're looking for ln(x), use the [log function](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/log.php) in `math.h` with `log(number)`.

Comment: log() from math.h is the natural log, so dividing by log(e) is silly.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, I was thinking it was log10 by default.

Comment: is this same thing as the pow function or different?

Comment: @KalebBrasee It's the TI-83 where log() is log10 by default, and ln is natural log.

Comment: @Tim And the 86 and 89 too, had both of those and they did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> `double pow(double x, double y);`
>
> The `pow()` function returns the value of x raised to the power of y.
>
> `double exp(double x);`
>
> The `exp()` function  returns the value of e (the base of natural logarithms) raised to the power of x.

So you want

```
pow(0.91831, exp(.773848284));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: use the log() function from <math.h>.  Or are you interested in an algorithm to compute it yourself?

Comment: sorry, it's for an iPhone application I am building. I have edited OP to reflect this. sorry for any confusion on my part.

Comment: I'd be surprised if math.h doesn't exist on the iphone, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `math.h` absolutely exists on the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't fully understood if you want to find the log or the exp. If don't want to use C's math library, you can write your own functions using a series expansion for approximation (for both functions).

You can find the general idea for Taylor series [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

For efficient log series you could read the "Series for calculating the natural logarithm" section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).

Comment: yeah i'm getting confused myself. i basically need to compute: 0.91831 is raised to the power of the inverse exponential of .773848284, or, 0.91831^2.168332164 = 0.831282

Comment: The thing confusing me is what you mean by "inverse exponential". From your example I see that e^(0.77384) = 2.16833, so do you maybe mean "exponential" and not "inverse exponential"?

Answer (score -2):

`man exp`
`man log`

Comment: lol that makes no sense. is there a term for this so i can look into it more?

Comment: **man** is Unix (Mac also) command for *manual*, i.e. a way to read documentation.

Comment: "man" is unix-speak for "manual."  It gives you a help page for that command/function